# Can you "store" javascript in a DB, and then execute it later time?

Tags: javascript, node.js

(please throw any concern for security or anything out the window, as its a internal application)

basically What i want to do is store a javascript function in a db:

```
 function x(name) {
   return name + 1;
 }
```

and then at a later time fetch the DB row

(pseudo code here)

```
 x = db.get('function').where('id').equals(1);

 console.log(x('bob'));
 //should print "bob +1 "
```

so here is the scenario i am envisioning:

basically, i am getting a JSON object, and depending on certain criteria, i want to do some transformation to that json, and output the new transformed json. for the sake of the "main" app, i dont want to hard code the transformation logic, instead it will be dynamic (dynamic in the sense that a different developer will provide it at run time)

so a DB might contain:

```
ID   |    javascript 
====================
1    |    (some js code)
2    |    (same func, different code)
```

what i want to do is execute that JS code stored in the DB, with an input of my choosing.

if it makes it easier, the function name will be standard.. i.e we can assume that the javascript saved in the DB will all follow:

```
function transform(input) {
  /* below this line logic will change

* end diff logic/
 return output
}
```

Comment: Should be doable, but you will need to use code evaluation of some kind.

Comment: Is that DB part of your JS program?

Comment: Javascript is just text and you can certainly store text in a database.  You can use `eval()` at any time to execute some Javascript text (with the associated risks of doing so).

Comment: I must add that usually one does not store and execute actual code this way, but rather some sort of meta data which a particular piece of code can then process to carry out the desired operations.  This also allows you to control what the stored data is allowed to do, whereas that is much harder if you store actual Javascript.

Comment: Just curious, why not have the web service method return the javascript code as `application/javascript` mime type and regular text?  That way you could just link to it without eval.

Comment: "(please throw any concern for security or anything out the window, as its a internal application)"    Really?  Internal applications don't need security? What planet do you live on?

Comment: a planet where internal application is isolated in the damage it can cause, and any damage caused is minuscule  compared to losing your damn job.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can execute any arbitrary string of JS using the [`eval()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval), which will return the result of whatever was evaluated.

So for your purposes, where you want to assign a variable to hold the (eval'ed) function that was in a string, you can do this:

```js
// retrieve string from DB somehow
var functionString = "(function whatever(name) { return name + 1; })";
var x = eval(functionString);
console.log(x("bob")); // logs "bob1"
```

Note that I've wrapped the function in the string in parentheses, because that makes it a function expression which can then be assigned to the variable `x`.

> *I dont want to hard code the transformation logic, instead it will be dynamic (dynamic in the sense that a different developer will provide it at run time)*

Another approach, in my opinion a better approach, is to put all of your transformation functions into a separate JavaScript module that you then `require()` as per the standard [Node.js module loading system](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html). That way the transformation logic is kept separate in another file that can be maintained separately by a different developer as needed, without mucking around with DB operations and `eval()`:

```
// transforms.js
module.exports = {
  "1" : function plus1(name) { return name + 1; },
  "2" : function square(x) { return x * x; },
  "3" : function half(x) { return x / 2; }
  // etc.
};

// in main JS file
var transforms = require("./transforms.js");

var a = transforms["2"];
var b = transforms["3"];
console.log(a(b(20))); // 100
console.log(transforms["1"]("bob")); // "bob1"
```

As you can see above, each of the "dynamic" transformation functions has been defined as a property of the object where the property names are the keys that you were going to use in your database.

StackOverflow code snippets don't seem to handle modules, but if you expand the following snippet you can see an equivalent of the above code working:

```js
// in "transform.js"
var transforms = {
  "1" : function plus1(name) { return name + 1; },
  "2" : function square(x) { return x * x; },
  "3" : function half(x) { return x / 2; }
  // etc.
};

// in main JS file
var a = transforms ["2"];
var b = transforms ["3"];
console.log(a(b(20))); // 100
console.log(transforms ["1"]("bob")); // "bob1"
```

Comment: Though I like the second approach, my only concern would be that the requires wont be dynamic, but loaded up at run-time.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `eval` to execute a String of JS. I don't know what you're doing nor what this is for, but this is highly discouraged.

Try running this in your web console:

```
eval('alert(\'hello\')')
```

Comment: pretty much what i stated in my OP.

I have a XML / Json message that is coming in (not sure which, it could be either) that needs to be transformed to some other object, unknown to my client. (my client will act merely as a middle man)

So basically

    SOME_INPUT --> my client --> transform --> SOME_OUTPUT --> "customer"


The customers (really just other applications) knows what the transformation they want.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that in JavaScript.
Here is an example.

```
var f = "function(x) {return x * 2}"
var x = 4;
eval("("+f+")("+x+")");
```

But this is very unsafe since you have no way to ensure that the function you are executing doesn't contain dangerous code.
Instead you could use an interpreter.
Either use an existing one like this
https://github.com/NeilFraser/JS-Interpreter

Or write your own. It doesn't have to be JS. If the language is very simple you can write an interpreter for it in an afternoon.

Answer (score 2):

Matthias Brantner with Oracle Labs recently demonstrated an experimental feature, Multilingual Engine (MLE), that allows JavaScript to be executed in Oracle Database:

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL_lVOJzXeE_8UwipLqfu6vKnOYDF3ITaI

The demos there include:

- JavaScript Module as UDF in SQL
- SQL Driver for JavaScript in Oracle Database
- Sequelize ORM in Oracle Database
- JavaScript Based Aggregate Function in SQL

Visit this page to get more info, download a VM that includes a DB + MLE, and provide feedback via the MLE Community: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/multilingual-engine/overview/index.html

Comment: And if you want to run JS inside Oracle DB immediately, check out https://blogs.oracle.com/nashorn/javascript-stored-procedures-and-nodejs-applications-with-oracle-database-12c

Answer (score 0):

`eval()` not so good decision to make *persistence for **active** objects*:

for example, let's look at a simple frame object:

`o = {
  type:'obj',
  value:'o',
  dump: function() { return "<"+this.type+":"+this.value+">" }
}`

`> {type: "obj", value: "o", dump: ƒ}`

And now we want to do `eval()`uable representation:

`o.toString()`

`"[object Object]"`

`JSON.stringify(o)`

`"{"type":"obj","value":"o"}"`

Very informative!