# Array of objects to database and back

Tags: javascript

I have array of functions/objects which I want to store to database, like this example:

```
function classPerson(firstName, lastName, activeStatus) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.activeStatus = activeStatus;
    this.identify = function () {
        return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
    }
} // element

var persons = [];
var personsFromDatabase = [];

// define persons
var personOne = new classPerson('Bruce', 'Lee', true);
var personTwo = new classPerson('Chuck', 'Norris', false);
var personThree = new classPerson('Steven', ' Seagal', true);

// add persons to array
persons.push(personOne);
persons.push(personTwo);
persons.push(personThree);

// show persons data
for (var i = 0; i < persons.length; i++) {
    alert(persons[i].identify());    
}

// store to database
var toDatabase = JSON.stringify(persons);        
alert(toDatabase);

// retrieve from database
var personsFromDatabase = JSON.parse(toDatabase);

// show persons data parsed from database
for (var i = 0; i < personsFromDatabase.length; i++) {
    alert(personsFromDatabase[i].identify());    
}
```

I transform persons array to string with JSON.stringify command and successfully store it to database.
When I load same string from database and transform back with JSON.parse to JS function/object I get list of simple objects (and error

> TypeError: personsFromDatabase[i].identify is not a function

) instead of classPerson function/object and in console I can see that difference, like on picture below:
[image: Console view]

How can I achieve to get array of functions/objects instead of simple JS objects?

[Fiddler link with example](https://jsfiddle.net/kendzi/q8an74vc/31/)

Comment: It's a bad idea, but see [Can you "store" javascript in a DB, and then execute it later time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38548039/can-you-store-javascript-in-a-db-and-then-execute-it-later-time)

Comment: JSON.stringify() ignores properties that are functions. You need to do `new classPerson()` for each item after parsing

Comment: Thanks to all for efforst and answers. You've helped me to understand this problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot save function in JSON, because function does not exist in JSON 
But you can use second argument of stringify function to replace the function with value.

Like

```
var json = JSON.stringify(obj, function(key, value) {
  if (typeof value === 'function') {
    return value.toString();
  } else {
    return value;
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I understand what it's all about and what is the problem! :)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, JSON has no functions as data types. You can only serialize strings, numbers, objects, arrays, and booleans (and null):

I have altered your example to provide a method to serialize and deserialize - which can be be as a basic template:

```
    function ClassPerson(firstName, lastName, activeStatus) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.activeStatus = activeStatus;
        this.identify = function () {
            return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
        }
    } // element

    ClassPerson.prototype.toJson = function() {
        var data = {};
        for(var prop in this) {
            if(this.hasOwnProperty(prop) && (typeof this[prop] !== 'function')) {
                data[prop] = this[prop];
            }
        }
        return JSON.stringify(data);
    };

    ClassPerson.fromJson = function(json) {
        var data = JSON.parse(json); // Parsing the json string.
        if(data) {
            var firstName = data.hasOwnProperty('firstName') ? data.firstName : "";
            var lastName = data.hasOwnProperty('lastName') ? data.lastName : "";
            var activeStatus = data.hasOwnProperty('activeStatus') ? data.activeStatus : "";
            return new ClassPerson(firstName, lastName, activeStatus);
        }
        return {};
    };

    function serializeClassPersons(personArray) {
        var serialised = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < personArray.length; i++) {
            serialised.push(persons[i].toJson());
        };
        return JSON.stringify(serialised);
    };
    function deserializeClassPersons(personsJsonString) {
        var jsonStringArray = JSON.parse(personsJsonString); // this is an array
        var persons = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < jsonStringArray.length; i++) {
            persons.push(ClassPerson.fromJson(jsonStringArray[i]));
        };
        return persons;
    };


    // add persons to array
    var persons = [
        new ClassPerson('Bruce', 'Lee', true),
        new ClassPerson('Chuck', 'Norris', false),
        new ClassPerson('Steven', ' Seagal', true)
    ];
    var personsFromDatabase = [];

    // show persons data
    console.log('Using ClassPerson.identify():');
    for (var i = 0; i < persons.length; i++) {
        console.log(persons[i].identify());
    };

    console.log('Using ClassPerson toJson() and fromJson()');
    for (var i = 0; i < persons.length; i++) {
        var jsonPerson = persons[i].toJson();
        console.log("json", jsonPerson);
        var personFromJson = ClassPerson.fromJson(jsonPerson);
        console.log("identify: ", persons[i].identify());
    };

    console.log('Serialize Persons Array to Json String');
    var personsJson = serializeClassPersons(persons);
    console.log(personsJson);

    console.log('DeSerialize Json Persons String to Array');
    var personsFromDatabase = deserializeClassPersons(personsJson);
    console.log(personsFromDatabase);
```

The Output of this is:

[image: Chrome Debug]

Comment: @Milos Your welcome, I also found a good article on JSON and class encoding (stringify) and decoding (parse) in Javascript using the technique outlined by Mujah Maskey above [link](https://javascript.info/json)